# Trying to understand why a thread could be blocked in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I am trying to get to the bottom of a threading problem in a web application. I am using Eclipse.  The problem is when one thread is a certain stage in a very long winded piece of code, another thread can't go any further even though it should. It has the appearance of a blocked thread. Eclipse has marked it as "stepping".  It makes no sense why it has stopped as there are no monitors, semaphores, sychnronization blocks anywhere near the code.

Can I use anything in eclipse to understand any reason why the thread looks like it is being blocked?

I can hit the pause button, which suspends the thread. When I click the resume button, it goes back to "stepping", but can't complete this simple line of code:

```
long beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you are debugging your program and it has reached a breakpoint.

Comment: I'll state the obvious (as of when I write this):  you are blocking on a call to System.currentTimeMillis().  This accesses the OS, so it is possible the problem is outside of the JVM and even Eclipse.  Check your long-winded code for suspicious OS access.  Other faint possiblility:  thread is waiting for a core to come free.  (I've found once something starts cranking on WinXP, the OS won't break it.  If you have old OS and only one core...)

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse, marking a thread as "Stepping" means that you are stepping through the code, either with step-in or (more likely) step-over, and the thread is blocked somehow either doing some IO, waiting for a synchronization lock, calling `wait()`, etc..  Eclipse is not controlling the thread and is waiting for the thread to move past the block before it can continue with the "stepping".  Once Eclipse has control back of the thread at the next line, your thread is changed to being "Suspended".

For example, while debugging the following test code:

```
// i put a break point here
System.out.println("Foo");
Object lock = new Object();
synchronized (lock) {
    // when I step over this line, my thread is labeled as "Stepping"
    lock.wait();
}
System.out.println("Boo");
```

Once I step over a method which blocks the thread, the thread gets labeled as "Stepping".

[image]

Comment: One other thread is "suspended" and has the paused icon. This the first thread in the problem scenario.  When this thread is at a certain stage, the other thread appears blocked - even though eclipse has marked it as "stepping".

Comment: I've edited my answer @dublintech.  I suspect that "stepping" is when you have stepped-in or (more likely) stepped-over a method which blocks the thread somehow.

Answer (score 1):

"Stepping" sounds like Eclipse thinks you're "stepping through the code" and currently at that line – that is, you're running in Debug mode. Is there a breakpoint set somewhere that you've missed?

Comment: I have removed all breakpoints, except the breakpoint needed to recreate this problem.

Comment: If you remove that last breakpoint as well, does the code make it past the `beginTime` line? What if you run in Run (instead of Debug) mode?